tkinter throwing an error but apparently working?
I'm trying to create a form where my users can select CSV files to then generate graphs from and I'm hitting an odd problem.
As part of the summary information, I am creating a label:
    self.title_label = ttk.Label(
        self,
        text='Graph not yet defined',
    )
    self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

which I later update using:
    self.title_label.configure(text=title)

and everything appears to work just fine, but when I look at the terminal output, every time I update the label, tkinter has thrown an error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/david/Programming/Python/GK-CC2/gk-cc2/modules/body_tabs/graphs.py", line 170, in edit_graph
    self.callbacks['update_summary'](self.graph_id)
  File "/home/david/Programming/Python/GK-CC2/gk-cc2/modules/body_tabs/graphs.py", line 65, in update_summary
    self.graph_objects[graph_id]['summary'].update_summary(
  File "/home/david/Programming/Python/GK-CC2/gk-cc2/modules/body_tabs/graphs.py", line 117, in update_summary
    self.title_label.configure(text=title)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!_graphsummary.!label"

The code's a bit long, so I've copied it to https://pastebin.com/NQQYSndT
The steps to recreate the error are:

Click on Add graph
On the summary that appears, click on Edit
Edit the details, including the title if you want to prove it changes
in the summary
Click on Save and exit

Close the main window and, Hey! Presto! The error shall appear!
I'm not looking for a code critique - I know the code isn't pretty and, at this stage, I'm not too bothered about that. I just want to understand what's going on and what (if anything) I can do about it.
Python 3.9.7 on Ubuntu 22.04, if that's relevant.

You should call mainloop() only once.

I could grow to dislike you ;-)  Thank you for showing this idiot far more patience than he deserves
